# Debugging React in Chrome with your profile/logged in

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I followed this documentation: [Using React in Visual Studio Code - Debugging React](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_debugging-react) but it opens up a new Chrome browser without my profiles. I need this to test React while being logged in. Is there a way to do this?